# Update android application programmatically

Tags: android

I have created a simple application and I wonder what are method of updating it directly from its interface. I want to create a script that checks for new updates and if any are found a button saying *"Download new update"* should be displayed. If the user clicks on it either  the new version is downloaded from the server, the running instance is closed and the downloaded file (.apk) is executed (to be installed), or update the existing one as the application is running (maybe the Android API has something for that).

Well, I am asking for some references, links or some clues. I also must specify that I don't want the settings and other local data to be deleted when installing the new version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584873/updating-an-application-ota

Comment: I think this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603912/update-an-internal-android-app-not-on-google-play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler way to do that is have to host the apk on your server and having a button in your app that opens the apk in the browser were the user can install it.

Comment: O.K. You are talking about a direct link to the .apk That could be a simple and quick of way of doing it. Now, what happens when I install an application over another with the same name? It is replaces? Are the settings and other local date deleted?

Comment: I actually don't have an android phone, but I'm sure it doesn't remove settings until the user removes the app. This is because the store it's self downloads the apk over the current app.

Comment: @ali yes, the application is replaced. No, the settings are not deleted.