# Update an internal android app not on Google Play?

Tags: android

I'm developing an internal application and it will not be on google play, how can I update this application?

Thanks a lot for all!

Comment: Depends on how you distributed it initially

Comment: this application will be installed on specific devices, are not available for general public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send people the new apk, or have it detect when there is a new version, and tell them to click on a link to download.

Comment: Yes, I believe that check if there is a new version and then ask for confirmation of the User is a good way, but I do not know how to check if existis a new version, this is the my biggest problem.

Comment: Put up a server with a /latestVersion API. The app will then periodically compare its own version to that, and prompt the user once a newer version is available.

Comment: Yes I will do that, create a service and then uses it, if there was a library ready for this would be easier but if I end up doing without nenuma library post the code here for helper the next.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to code the server in node.js, here's the code:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.get('/version'', function(req, res){
    res.send('99');
});
app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google play provide a very powerful way to push updates of a given app , if you will override this way you will be obliged to redeploy your app "manually" (new apk sent to x given devices)

Or make your app have it's content linked to a server and this way the only thing that will be updated will be the "data" on the server side .

Comment: I believe that Google play is the best way to keep updated apps, and also the simplest way, but in this case I can not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by mounting a server that keeps a file with `apk` and information from them and rode a lib that makes communication and install the update, as I did at work I'll have to wait the people here to post the lib on github it, but if someone need uses before me post the lib here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply distributing the .apk to your internal users is probably the easiest way to get started, however you will have to implement a custom update process for this.

By now there are more options available that will handle the update process, e.g. [Private Channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992) (for Google Apps users), Alpha/beta stages for internal distribution (more like a hack..) or complex [MDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) solutions.

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378605/1024108) in [Google Play deployment for internal company user only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371812/google-play-deployment-for-internal-company-user-only) for reference.